# Question about the position vector of an object(godot)

Tags: vector, godot

I have a scene in godot where there is a missile at the origin of the plane and I have another scene where I have a static platform "hanging in the air", the platform has a Position2d as child object and my goal is to create the missile on the Position2d object and direct it to wherever the player is. I was able to instantiate the missile scene at runtime, but I don't understand how to direct it towards the player. At this point I have a doubt (as per the question) about the vectors: considering the point where the missile is instantiated on the platform (which is far from the origin of the plane), does the position vector of the missile start from the origin of the plane and end on the point where the missile is? Or does it start directly from the point of the missile and end up I don't know where? Can anyone give me some clarification on this?

Answer (score 2):

Side step the issue by working with global coordinates (`global_position` and `global_transform`).

---

Your vectors exist in a vector space. You should do your operation in the same vector space. The question is, in which vector space are your vectors?

While we are talking about the scene tree, the vector spaces are defined by the `transform` of the nodes. So the `position` of a node is respect to the origin of the parent node. In fact, the node exists in the vector space of the parent node, which may include rotation or scaling, for example.

Consequence of that, if you move a node, you also move all its children. If you rotate a node, you also rotate all its children, and so on.

You can also get transforms, and thus positions, relative to the origin of the scene tree. For that you use the `global_transform` (and `globa_position`). There are also helper methods `to_local` and `to_global` to convert between the two.

---

> I have another scene where I have a static platform "hanging in the air", the platform has a Position2d as child object and my goal is to create the missile on the Position2d object and direct it to wherever the player is.

Since - I suppose - moving the platform should not move the missile. That is, the missile should move on its own, not attached to the platform. I'm going to suggest not making the missile a child of the platform. You can instance the missile and attach it to the scene tree root, for example. Or you may have a node dedicated for the purpose of holding the missiles.

Now, since you would be placing the missile as a child of a different node, let us work with global positions (and by extension with global transforms). Thus, ask the `Position2D` for its `global_position` (a.k.a `global_transform.origin`), then tell the missile to set is `global_position` to that:

```
missile.global_position = $Position2D.global_position
get_tree().get_root().add_child(missile)
```

*By the way, if you are adding the missiles as children of the platform - which is ok as long as the platform does not move - you can still use `global_position` for this purpose. However in that particular case using `position` instead of `global_position` has the same result. That is because the `Position2D` and the missile would be siblings (have the platform as parent) and thus would be in the same vector space.*

---

> I was able to instantiate the missile scene at runtime, but I don't understand how to direct it towards the player

I strongly encourage having a script on the missile, where you can have a `func` you call to aim it, and then you can work it out there. *Note: I'm assuming this missile will not track the player.* The signature is something like this:

```
func aim(target_position:Vector2) -> void:
    pass
```

Then when you instance the missile, you can call `aim` on it, passing the  `global_position` of the player:

```
missile.aim(player.global_position)
```

The `position` of the player is relative to whatever the parent of the player is. And the missile, nor the platform are aware (and should not be aware) of what that is. So use `global_position` instead. *That is, since you as developer know what the parent node of the player is, you can hardcode that logic there. But then you would need to remember to change that if you decide to change where the player is in the scene tree. So just don't! Use `global_position`.*

In fact, let us rename the parameter:

```
func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    pass
```

---

What do we need to do in that `func`? We need to compute a direction. We can do that:

```
var _direction:Vector2

func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    _direction = global_position.direction_to(target_global_position)
```

Here we are figuring out the direction in global space (both vectors are in the same vector space, so we know this operation makes sense). Assuming there is no rotation or anything like that involved, this is ok. However, just to be sure, let us bring that to local space:

```
var _direction:Vector2

func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    _direction = to_local(global_position.direction_to(target_global_position))
```

By the way, just so you know, that is equivalent to this:

```
var _direction:Vector2

func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    _direction = global_transform.affice_inverse().xform(
        global_position.direction_to(target_global_position)
    )
```

---

And we might want to rotate the missile:

```
var _direction:Vector2

func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    _direction = to_local(global_position.direction_to(target_global_position))
    rotation = _direction.angle()
```

Or we can do it like this:

```
var _direction:Vector2

func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    # …
    rotation = get_angle_to(target_global_position)
```

Or like this:

```
var _direction:Vector2

func aim(target_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    # …
    look_at(target_global_position)
```

*Yes, both `get_angle_to` and `look_at` expect a global position.*

---

Finally, you would want to move the missile. You can, for example, can use the direction to compute a velocity (multiplying the direction by the speed you want), and use that to move the missile.

Comment: I mean another thing: I know that the point of the missile (i.e. where it is instantiated) is a vector but the thing I'm wondering is: does the position vector of the missile start from the origin of the axes and end where the pivot of the missile texture is? Or does it start from the origin of the missile texture and to see where it ends I have to do some calculations on the position vector itself in order to determine the direction? This is strictly necessary for me because I want to account for doing the vector operations. Everything here

Comment: @Gius texture? You would place a `Sprite` relative to your physics object. I'm assuming the missile is the physics object. And then how the `Sprite` is relative to it is secondary. If by pivot you mean the `offset` of the `Sprite`, that is used to position the texture of the `Sprite` and should not affect anything else. If you need something like the position of the tip of the missing (matching the texture), I encourage adding a `Position2D` for that, so you don't need to do as much vector operations. Perhaps I'm taking the wrong assumptions?

Comment: I misspoke. Anyway the missile scene is an area2d which is the parent node so I have to refer to its pivot(area2d), and here comes the question: if I have to refer to the pivot of area2d as the point where the missile is, does the position vector of the missile start from the origin of the axes and then end on the pivot of area2d? That's what I'm interested in. Or am I not understanding how a vector works if my question is wrong?

Comment: @Gius The `position` of the `Area2D` is relative to its parent. And the `Area2D` would have `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D` as children, and their `position` is relative to the `Area2D`. And the same parent-children relationship applies everywhere. For a node, its parent is at position `(0,0)`. So you can think of the `position` as a vector starting at the pivot of the parent and ending at theirs. Or use `global_position` which you can think of as a vector starting at the origin of the scene tree root and ending at the node pivot. Well, unless you mean something else by pivot.

Comment: @Gius I want to point out that the `global_position` is not simply the result of adding the `position` down the scene tree until you reach the node. That is because there would be transformations other than translation. Instead, the `global_transform` is the result of composing the `transform` down the scene tree until you reach the node. And the `global_position` is the origin of the `global_transform`. Similarly the `position` is the origin of the `transform`. Each `transform` representing a vector space (Edit: with its own axis) that could be translated, rotated, scaled, and so on.